# Multiple Jquery dropdown menus remain open after clicking on another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I've modified the code on several places now and I've come up with the following solution:  `jsfiddle.net/u2158392/2g8poyxh/`

It's working pretty well, but I'm looking for a way to close the other dropdown menus which are still open when I'm clicking on another one.

So how can I make sure only one dropdown menu can be activated on the page at all times?

Thanks in advance!